# Using Boost.Log on Android for logcats

Tags: c++, logging, boost, android-ndk

I'm attempting to use Boost.Log (in v1.57) to write logs to multiple platforms, Android included. For the NDK code we have, I need to send log messages down to `__android_log_print`.

After reading the documentation over and over (The whole system is pretty complex), it seems that I either need to write my own logging backend. Alternatively, it seems I could use their existing ostream backend and write my own stream (with Boost.Iostream).

The thing is, a stream isn't really appropriate for this if you think about it. I won't necessarily have a buffer that I'm storing the logs inside of. I'm just forwarding them along to the aforementioned Android NDK function.

What is the proper solution here? IO streams or custom backend for the logger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest creating a custom sink backend which forwards the log messages to the android logging function.
The following example code implements this and uses the android log levels so that you can filter log messages based on the log level. You can of course define your own log levels and add a mapping between your log level and the android ones.

You need to call `boost_android_logging::init()` once, then you can instantiate a `boost_android_logging::Logger` wherever you need one and send log messages using `BOOST_LOG_SEV`.

```
#include <iostream>

typedef enum android_LogPriority {
    ANDROID_LOG_UNKNOWN = 0,
    ANDROID_LOG_DEFAULT,
    ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE,
    ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,
    ANDROID_LOG_INFO,
    ANDROID_LOG_WARN,
    ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,
    ANDROID_LOG_FATAL,
    ANDROID_LOG_SILENT,
} android_LogPriority;


int fake__android_log_print(int prio, const char *tag, const char *fmt, ...)
{
  std::cout << prio << " " << tag << ": " << fmt << std::endl;
  return 0;
}


#include <boost/log/attributes.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp>
#include <boost/log/core.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
#include <boost/log/expressions/keyword.hpp>

namespace boost_android_logging
{

  BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(severity, "Severity", android_LogPriority)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(module, "Module", std::string)

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;

struct android_sink_backend : public sinks::basic_sink_backend<logging::sinks::concurrent_feeding>
{
    void consume(const logging::record_view& rec)
    {
        android_LogPriority log_sev = rec[severity].get();
        const char* log_msg = rec[expr::smessage].get().c_str();

        const char* log_module = "unknown";

        if (rec[module])
        {
            log_module = rec[module].get().c_str();
        }

        // forward to actual logging function
        fake__android_log_print(log_sev, log_module, log_msg);
    }
};

typedef boost::log::sources::severity_logger<android_LogPriority> Logger;

void init()
{
    logging::add_common_attributes();
    typedef sinks::synchronous_sink<android_sink_backend> android_sink;
    boost::shared_ptr<android_sink> sink = boost::make_shared<android_sink>();

    sink->set_filter(severity >= ANDROID_LOG_INFO);
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}

void shutdown()
{
    logging::core::get()->remove_all_sinks();
}

} // namespace boost_android_logging


#define SET_MODULE(logger,log_module)  logger.add_attribute(boost_android_logging::module.get_name(), boost::log::attributes::constant<std::string>(#log_module));

struct Demo
{
  Demo()
  {
    SET_MODULE(logger, Demo);
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, ANDROID_LOG_WARN) << "this is a warning"; 
  }

  void test()
  {
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, ANDROID_LOG_FATAL) << "fatal error occured";
  }

  boost_android_logging::Logger logger;
};

int main()
{
  boost_android_logging::init();

  boost_android_logging::Logger logger;
  SET_MODULE(logger, main);

  BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, ANDROID_LOG_WARN) << "this is a warning";
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG) << "this will be filtered";
  BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger, ANDROID_LOG_FATAL) << "fatal error occured";

  Demo d;
  d.test();
  boost_android_logging::shutdown();
}
```

<kbd>[live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bf059ba3daf4b37)</kbd>

Comment: Did you write this just now or is there a generic android solution somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: @void.pointer I wrote this, I am not aware of a ready-made android solution.

Comment: The android log print function actually takes 4 arguments, one being a tag. The tag is unique to the module, I think. I'm not sure how you'd pass that in (could be an attribute, but then you'd have to specify it each time you log, which is annoying).

Comment: @void.pointer I updated the question, you can set add an attribute once to the logger

Comment: Thanks that is super helpful. One last question, if I were to use my own enum (say, that the enum maps differently per platform, like windows vs android), would I have to use a formatter in the sink frontend to map them differently? Or would the consume method handle the mapping internally via switch statement or std::map of sorts?

Comment: @void.pointer you can use a  `switch` in `consume()` or you can use [`custom_severity_mapping`](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/sinks/syslog/custom_severity_mapping.html) or [`direct_severity_mapping`](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/sinks/syslog/direct_severity_mapping.html)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the 'syslog' part of Boost.Log is, so I'm not sure if I can use those mapping objects. Documentation is pretty sparse on details. Seems simpler to just handle the generic severity levels in a switch or map in the backend. Thanks for the info!